# Cannot read property 'nTable' of null

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I recently set up my first try with datatables.

When I test my Site I'll get a few errors in my console.... Anyone got an idea how to solve them?

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nTable' of null
_fnCallbackFire @ jquery.dataTables.js:5242
_fnLog @ jquery.dataTables.js:5070
(anonymous function) @ jquery.dataTables.js:6111
m.extend.each @ jquery.js:2
m.fn.m.each @ jquery.js:2
DataTable @ jquery.dataTables.js:6092
$.fn.DataTable @ jquery.dataTables.js:14775
(anonymous function) @ datatable.php:134
m.Callbacks.j @ jquery.js:2
m.Callbacks.k.fireWith @ jquery.js:2
m.extend.ready @ jquery.js:2
J @ jquery.js:2
```

The Scripts are loaded in the header section. via including the header.php It doesn't change anything when i put the directly into the page.

The following scripts are loaded:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="/assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="/assets/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="/assets/js/dataTables.tableTools.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="/assets/js/dataTables.editor.js"></script>
```

Versions:

- jQuery v1.11.3
- DataTables 1.10.7
- TableTools 2.2.4
- dataTables.editor 1.4.2

You can find my Code right here: https://ghostbin.com/paste/46x7v

Comment: Post the table html!!

Comment: From the link given I see that your are trying to `initialize` editor before initializing `dataTables`. Interchange them and try!!

Comment: No Chnage with that prcedure

Comment: most probably you're referring to a wrong table ID or there is a duplicate ID in the HTML

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in DataTables initialization code where `colums` should be `columns` instead.

```
$('#adminlist').DataTable( {
    dom: "Tfrtip",
    ajax: "assets/php/table.admins.php",
    columns: [
        {data: "id" },
        {data: "name" },
        {data: "joindate" },
        {data: "section" },
        {data: "tutor" },
        {data: "lesson1" },
        {data: "lesson2" },
        {data: "lesson3" },
        {data: "versus" },
        {data: "insults" }
    ],
    tableTools: {
        sRowSelected: "os",
        aButtons: [
            { sExtends: "editor_create", editor: editor },
            { sExtends: "editor_edit",   editor: editor },
            { sExtends: "editor_remove", editor: editor }
        ]
    }
});
```

Also your tag `<section class="container"` is not closed, should be `<section class="container">`.

Comment: Still the same issue.

Comment: @Exylian, found another issue, please correct and try again.

Comment: In my case, I was initializing Datatables to tbody instead of initializing to the table itself. This might not be your case but may help you to troubleshoot if it is.